# Using PIMPL with singletons and auto_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, pimpl-idiom

I have a singleton with a number of static methods and instance methods. I'd like to export it in a DLL so that I can use it elsewhere. However, doing so generated a compiler warning because I wasn't exporting the private data members of the class.

So, in my research, I came across the PIMPL idiom and saw that it could be used for doing just what I want to do. Please let's refrain from the while "Singletons are evil/anti-patterns" argument. In my case it makes sense because I need a manager class for all my sub-objects. For brevity, I'm going to cut down on some of the other methods in the class, but I'll leave enough for the general idea.

The idea for the empty `HIDDevice` destructor in the `HIDDeviceImpl` CPP file comes from [this article](http://acehreli.org/turkcecpp/auto_ptr_incomplete.html) by Ali Çehreli

**HIDDevice.hpp**

```
class HIDDeviceImpl; // Forward Declaration

class HIDDevice
{
public:

    static HIDDevice* getDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID);

    int writeData(const unsigned char *data, int length);


    int readData(unsigned char *data, int length);

    ~HIDDevice(); // Note public destructor declared in HIDDevice.hpp

private:

    std::unique_ptr<HIDDeviceImpl> m_pImpl; // pointer to the implemetation
};
```

**HIDDevice.cpp**

```
#include "HIDDeviceImpl.hpp"
#include "HIDDevice.hpp"

HIDDevice* HIDDevice::getDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID)
{
    return HIDDeviceImpl::getDevice(vendorID, productID);
}

int HIDDevice::writeData(const unsigned char *data, int length)
{
    return m_pImpl->writeData(data, length);
}


int HIDDevice::readData(unsigned char *data, int length)
{
    return m_pImpl->readData(data, length);
}
```

**HIDDeviceImpl.hpp**

```
#include "HIDDevice.hpp"

class HIDDeviceImpl : public HIDDevice
{
public:

    static HIDDeviceImpl* getDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID);

    int writeData(const unsigned char *data, int length);

    int readData(unsigned char *data, int length);

private:
    // some private static and private member functions and data
    // private constructor and destructor
};
```

**HIDDeviceImpl.hpp**

```
#include "HIDDeviceImpl.hpp"

/** Non-member Static Data Definitions **/
/** internal map used to store all HIDDevice objects */
static std::map<std::string, HIDDeviceImpl*> m_hidDevices;

HIDDeviceImpl* HIDDeviceImpl::getDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID) 
{
    //implementation
}

int HIDDeviceImpl::writeData(const unsigned char *data, int length)
{
    //implementation
}

int HIDDeviceImpl::readData(unsigned char *data, int length)
{
    //implementation
}

HIDDeviceImpl::HIDDeviceImpl(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID, std::string serialNumber)
{
    // implementation
}

HIDDeviceImpl::~HIDDeviceImpl()
{
    // implementation
}

// Note the HIDDevice destructor is declared in the HIDDeviceImpl file.
HIDDevice::~HIDDevice()
{
    // intentionally left blank
}
```

Now, the error this generates is the following:

```
error C2248: 'HIDDeviceImpl::~HIDDeviceImpl' : cannot access private member declared in class 'HIDDeviceImpl'
```

This is stemming from the `auto_ptr` in **HIDDevice.hpp**

Comment: While `std::auto_ptr` was a good first attempt at bringing smart pointers to the world of C++, it is a flawed one, and `std::auto_ptr` have been deprecated since C++11 and will be removed in C++17. Either use manual pointer management or use the new [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: `unique_ptr` and related ptrs were created to replace the broken `auto_ptr`. Note that the article is from 2002.

Comment: The pImpl class in the Pimpl idiom does not derive from the "public class". In fact, the public class shouldn't appear anywhere in the pImpl, because otherwise you have a circular referencing

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yeah, that's what I noticed. So I guess `HIDDevice` would also have to be a singleton?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the heads up, I'll change it.

Comment: @audiFanatic Only HIDDeviceImpl should be a singleton. HIDDevice could just be a namespace at best, with "static" functions only.

Comment: @KABoissonneault So I guess I wouldn't have to ever return an `HIDDevice` nor an `HIDDeviceIMpl`?

Comment: @audiFanatic Exactly. Keep only `writeData` and `readData` in `HIDDevice`, and make the implementation of those functions call those functions on the singleton internally. Much less trouble for the user

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do what the error message is telling you to do, and make the destructor public?  That way, the internals of `std::unique_ptr` has access to it.

Comment: Because I don't want the object to be destroyed prematurely by programmer error.

Comment: @audiFanatic It won't be destroyed early by a programmer error, because `m_pImpl` is only accessible from within HIDDevice (because it's private)

Comment: @KABoissonneault True, I guess I'll try to implement an actual PIMPL first (as per your other comments) and then I'll give this a go.